# Is Spark Streaming good for processing randomly timed data?

Tags: architecture, stream, apache-spark

I'm evaluating Apache Spark and its Spark Streaming component for a backend of a web app & external API. With such a setup, the backend will receive a lot of data that is not uniformly timed: e.g. in response to user actions on the website. **Edit:** In most cases, I'll want a real-time response for the user. The faster the better, but latency of 1-3 seconds is ok. A sample use case is the user requesting to see a statistical graph in the web UI.

From the documentation, I understand that the fundamental model of Spark Streaming is data processed at equal intervals (the "batch duration"), e.g. of 1 second or so.

The batching that Spark Streaming performs could perhaps be useful to reduce the number of RPCs from my Frontend to my Backend: from one-per-event to one-per-second.

But besides that this architecture seems to have flaws:

- Processing events at fixed intervals, and not as they occur.

  The slightly unusual control flow in Spark Streaming programs:

  ```
  doSparkStreaming() {
    <define processing on data; unclear how it gets called later>
    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();
  }
  ```

  Unnecessary polling of data sources during long times of user inactivity.

I'm leaning towards NOT using it. Am I perhaps missing something?

Many thanks.

Comment: What usecases are you considering? It all depends on the usecase.

Comment: There is not enough info here to make a decision, all I can tell from this is your use case is getting lots of data that is not uniformly timed. I'm not even sure streaming is the right model for this, IK there is already an answer but I think you could receive a much better one if you gave more details on your use case

Comment: @aaronman, maasg: Thanks - I added latency requirements (1-3 sec) and use case (interactive web UI) in first paragraph. What do you think?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to use spark streaming (or similar) to receive a request for a webpage and deliver data? And what has been called 'not uniformly timed' are those user requests?  What is the data being requested? Where is it stored?

Comment: @maasg: Yes, that's right. We realize this is not standard architecture, and we're only considering Spark Streaming because we also have many use cases for periodic computation, without any latency requirements. Plus Spark has a machine learning lib and integration with distributed DBs, which we'll definitely need one way or another. The overall system is for business processes monitoring/analytics. Do you think, based on the requirements stated in my question, that we should look for something else?

Comment: @maasg: I wondered if I could ask you for a final comment on this - would be great to resolve this question. Apologies for not stating it well enough at the outset. Many thanks.

Comment: @JanZankowski IMO, what you're looking for is what's commonly called "Serving Layer" that takes care of serving users request from data that has already been processed by your analytics pipeline. In contrast, Spark Streaming is *part* of your analytics pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is on target: Apache Spark in its current form is not likely the best choice. I would recommend instead a queuing system e.g. Kafka or possibly a Cassandra/Storm based approach.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can justify this answer, spark streaming can definitely be used to track user activity

Comment: @aaronman  The OP pointed out issues with using Spark IN THIS USE CASE. Spark streaming is not a perfect match for real time and or erratic events - precisely what is in the OP.  You are talking about user activity - too broad to be useful as a comment. Instead focus on the delivery rate and regularity and required reporting latencies.

Comment: spark streaming definitely processes data in realtime, he doesn't specify wether he needs the response in realtime (though there are uses of spark in realtime). As for your suggestions kafka is mostly for ingesting logs not for doing real calculations, storm has a very constrained model compared to spark so if he needs any sort of complex flows on his data storm is out. I don't know much about cassandra it does seem like a possible choice, but even then spark actually has a connector to cassandra that makes it (debatably) easier to use.

Comment: Lastly (ran out of space on last comment) non uniformly timed data is somewhat meaningless and vague, unless data is coming from some sort of automated process it won't be uniform and there is no reason to think spark-streaming can only handle that case

Comment: Sorry to make you read this wall of text, I noticed that you said cassandra/storm approach so I take back my comment about storm, but everything else still stands

Comment: my point is that kafka has no MR framework around it so any processing you do on it will have to based on w/e data comes from that broker, rather than the whole set, also spark streaming has a kafka connector which would give you more functionality